# How to obtain a closed-form solution for the following integral? Please give me a hand.

Tags: integration

How to obtain a closed-form solution for the following integral?

The integral is as follows

[image: Integral]

where $m_1$, $m_2$, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are all positive. And $v_1$ and $v_2$ are both integer.

Comment: Many thanks for the editor.

Comment: Aren't $\nu_1,\nu_2$ integer ?

Comment: Yes， the two variables are integer.

Comment: If I am right, by a linear change of variable you can eliminate two parameters and rewrite as $$\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty(\lambda^2+1)^{-\nu_1-1/2}(\lambda^2+a\lambda+b)^{-\nu_2-1/2}d\lambda.$$

Comment: Yes， that is right. But how to get the integral down?

Comment: I am not sure whether there exist a closed-form solution for the above integral. Is it possible to prove that there exist or not a closed-form solution?

Comment: I tried a few cases with Alpha. Bad news, for small exponents the indefinite integral requires an Elliptic integral, larger exponents yield no solution.

Comment: How about for large values of $v_1$ and $v_2$? How about the case in ($v_1$ +1)/2>>0 and ($v_2$ +1)/2>>0? If $v_1$=$v_2$, is there any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, for large exponents, the integrand is asymptotic to $\lambda^{-2\nu_1-2\nu_2-2}$, very quickly decaying, and the tails bring little contribution. I don't think that an easy approximation is possible.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I tried to derive an approximate solution for the integral using Laplace's method, but also failed.

Comment: But interestingly when I tried some particular values of  $m_1$, $m_2$, $v_1$ and $v_2$, I can find an exact solution for the above integral. It seems that there exist a closed-form solution, but we cannot find it easily.

Comment: For what values ?

Comment: For example, when $m_1$=10, $m_2$=12,  $u_1$=0, $u_2$=1, $v_1$=$v_2$=5, the integral is 1065125*5^0.5*pi/5445468.

Comment: What about the $\mu$'s ?

Comment: When I tried other values, I cannot find solution for the above integral even with mathematica software.

Comment: I know, I told you.

Comment: If $v_1 $ and $v_2 $ are odd then you will have a polynomial in the denominator that can be decomposed using partial fractions. Otherwise, this form of integral is unlikely to be integrated without using special functions. See specifically the Appell hypergeometric function https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AppellHypergeometricFunction.html. Another plausible route is to use contour integration.